# NewInstance deprecated and using getDeclaredConstructor

Tags: android

Well I am currently using an android library that provides me with Material intro but there is just a small problem when I use

```
addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance(title, description, image, backgroundColor));
```

It says it's deprecated while I found out I should use getDeclaredConstructor but the end I fail because I cannot customize the title or things I wish that it would work but I failed on it many times

Any suggestion how should I use this line to show the same results but with different code ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the deprecation depends on the method of the library itself. If you click + shift on AppIntroFragment, you'll see 2 deprecated newInstance methods.

The solution is to use the actual methods, listed below in the file (but not mentioned in the Readme, as far as i know). Try something like this:

```
addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("title", getString(R.string.intro_typeface), getString(R.string.intro_description), getString(R.string.intro_typeface), R.drawable.icon, getColor(R.color.introBackgroundColor), getColor(R.color.textColorIntroPrimary), getColor(R.color.textColorIntroSecondary)));
```

Tested and working in my app.